# Cannot pass array object from map function as argument javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to figure out why I cannot pass array object from map function as argument to function `createModal(student)` that is called onclick:
The error is caused by the parameter because when I tried function `createModal()` it worked fine.

```
const allWorkshops = await fetch("/api/workshops/detail");
const data = await allWorkshops.json();
result.innerHTML = "";
counter = 0;

data.forEach((workshop) => {
  ...
  ${workshop.students.map(student =>
     `<li class="list-group-item">
        <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal" type="button" onclick="createModal(${student})">${student.first_name} ${student.last_name}</a>
      </li>`
  ).join("")}
  ...
});
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846769/cannot-pass-object-as-argument) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)) question and tried changing the code as following but it did not work either:

```
...
${workshop.students.map(function(student) {
   var studentCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student));
   return `<li class="list-group-item">
             <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal" type="button" onclick="createModal(${studentCopy})">${student.first_name} ${student.last_name}</a>
           </li>`
}).join("")}
...
```

Unfortunately I don't know the exact error because the only thing I see in inspect in Chrome is this. Which is at the beggining of index file and does not help me.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (at (index):1:21)

**EDIT:**
I have updated the code to look as following. It kinda works but the problem is that is have a table for workshops and every row has a list with the students inside and instead of appending students to the right workshop it appends them to the first list other are empty.

```
const workshopList = document.querySelector(".workshop-list");

async function getData(){
  const allWorkshops = await fetch("/api/workshops/detail");
  const data = await allWorkshops.json();
  data.forEach((workshop) => {
      var studentList = document.querySelector(".student-list");
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");
      tr.classList.add("responsive-table__row");
      tr.innerHTML = `
          <td class="responsive-table__body__text responsive-table__body__text--name">
              <ul class="list-group student-list">
                  ${workshop.students.forEach(student => {
                      let li = document.createElement('li');
                      li.classList.add('list-group-item');
                      let anchor = document.createElement('a');
                      anchor.dataset.bsToggle = 'modal';
                      anchor.dataset.bsTarget = '#studentModal';
                      anchor.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                      anchor.addEventListener('click', () => createModal(student));
                      anchor.innerText = student.last_name;
                      li.appendChild(anchor);
                      studentList.appendChild(li);
                  })}
              </ul>
          </td>
      `
      workshopList.appendChild(tr);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`student` is an object. When you try to interpolate it into the template literal, it gets turned into the string `[Object object]`, which isn't a meaningful argument to `create_modal()`.

Instead of interpolating, you should create the element using DOM methods, and use `addEventListener()` with a closure to bind the click listener.

```js
data.forEach((workshop) => {
  //...
  workshop.students.forEach(student => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('list-group-item');
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.dataset.bsToggle = 'modal';
    anchor.dataset.bsTarget = '#studentModal';
    anchor.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    anchor.addEventListener('click', () => createModal(student));
    anchor.innerText = student.last_name;
    li.appendChild(anchor);
    studentList.appendChild(li);
  });
  //...
});
```

Comment: You don't put JavaScript inside HTML like that. You need to do everything with DOM methods, not creating HTML strings.

Comment: `document.createElement("td")`, etc.